# Searching in Dropbox using SearchAsync not showing all results in C# using .NET SDK API v2

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropbox, dropbox-api

Suppose I want to show all files from a Dropbox folder using SearchAsync in C#.
The "query" argument of SearchAsync is mandatory so that it filters records from the Dropbox folder files. How could I populate all files from a folder using SearchAsync.File indexing is required so that I have to use SearchAsync. I'm using the SearchAsync like below-

await client.Files.SearchAsync("path"," ");

If anyone has any idea please share.

Answer (score 0):

The [`SearchAsync`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesRoutes_SearchAsync_1.htm) method requires a query, and doesn't support listing everything in a folder.

Instead, to list everything in a folder, you should use the [`ListFolderAsync`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesRoutes_ListFolderAsync_1.htm) method.

Comment: If I use ListFolderAsync then waht is the way of pagination? I couldn't find any pagination option with ListFolderAsync. @Greg

Comment: The response from `ListFolderAsync` is automatically paged. You should check `HasMore` on the [`ListFolderResult`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/T_Dropbox_Api_Files_ListFolderResult.htm) and if it's true, call back to [`ListFolderContinueAsync`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesRoutes_ListFolderContinueAsync_1.htm). Likewise, check `HasMore` from that result, and so on.